# about the sqlite query

Tags: sqlite

I just saw a sqlite query and I cannot find what is it mean on the Internet.

```
                SELECT _id," +
                "NULL AS data1," +
                "NULL AS data2," +
                "artist_key||' '||album_key AS match from ....
                           ^^^^^^^
```

Are there anyone know what is    ||' '||   mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is the string concatenation operator. From the [documenation](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_expr.html):

> The || operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings
>   of its operands.

So in your case, the column `match` in the result will contain the `artist_key` column joined with the `album_key` column, with a space in-between.